# Wordpress get display location in nav_menu_submenu_css_class filter

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Maybe I am thinking about this too much. Hopefully I am not. I would like to add a class `dropdown-menu animated` to all sub menus in the wp_nav_menu that are in a particular location without using a walker. I realise there is a filter for this called `nav_menu_submenu_css_class` but I am unable to determine the location of the menu. This is my code;

```
function mi_submenu_css( $classes, $args, $depth )
{
    print_r ($args); echo "JTGO";
    /*if ('header-menu' === $args->theme_location) {*/
        $display_depth = ($depth + 1);
        array_push($classes, 'dropdown-menu animated fadeOutUp menu-depth-' . $display_depth);
    /*}*/
    return $classes;
}
```

I expected $args to contain the menu location but comes back empty. You can see I have tried to print it out as an array.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the problem I had to specify the number of arguments in my filter. So instead of having;

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', 'mi_submenu_css' );
```

I changed it to;

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', 'mi_submenu_css', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: It would be great to see your entire final answer here for others that don't comprehend the code in its entirety. Also don't forget to mark your own answer as the accepted answer.